# Android SDk Manager - Download SDK 3.0 to 3.2

Tags: android, sdk

When my Android SDK Manager opens up it shows me SDK 4.0.3 and then 2.3.3, 2.2 and 2.1

Why is the 3.x SDK not listed ?

I am using Windows OS

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm seeing the same behavior on Mac OS X. The 3.0 - 3.2 SDKs aren't visible at all in the SDK manager. I have all filtering boxes ("Updates/New", "Installed", "Obsolete") checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your Android SDK manager is out of date.  The older verions do not list those SDKs.  I just updated to Android SDK Tools revision 20, which you can do from your Android SDK Manager.  Open SDK Manager, select Android SDK Tools, click "Install 1 Package" in the bottom right corner, and wait for the SDK Manager to basically update itself.  At the end, you have to close and re-open the SDK manager, and those SDKs will be listed.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using proxy network, open the Android SDK manager.

Go to *tools -> options* and give the proxy address and port number, and restart Android SDK manager.

It will show the updates and packages which are yet to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Click on "open the Android SDK Manager" from Toolbar in Eclipse, after that one window is popup then select android 3.* and other packages and click on install packages button after that one more popup is displaying then select accept all and click install button and see below link also, sorry for my bad English communication.

[Adding Packages](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the icon on the toolbar in Eclipse that says "Opens the Android SDK Manager".

You will displayed the packages that are already installed in your system and the ones that are missing.

Select the package you want to install. ( Android 3.0 and 3.1 in your case).

In the next screens, click on "Accept All" and "Install".